# Using HttpClient synchronously results in memory leak

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mono

When trying to call `HttpClient.SendAsync()` synchronously in a loop, memory used by the process keeps growing (as reported by "Activity" in Instruments).
Below is the simplest repro I could create (add at the end of `ViewController.ViewDidLoad()` in a new Xamarin.iOS Single View App).

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
    var requestUri = "images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    while (true)
    {
        using (var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength);
        }
        Task.Delay(10).Wait();
    }
});
```

Making it async solves the issue:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
    var requestUri = "images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    while (true)
    {
        using (var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength);
        }
        await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
});
```

At this point I am not sure if the leak is expected in the synchronous code or if it is an actual bug in mono.

Environment:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.5.3
- Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   13.16.0.13 (b75deaf)

Comment: if you think you've found a bug, then file an issue in the Xamarin Github

Comment: @Jason will do, just wanted to run it by SO first in case I missed something obvious

Comment: All I can say is, there is no leak whatsoever on windows 8.1 when run with .net core 3.0.1, so there should be nothing obvious you are missing

Comment: Your sync version did not delay 10ms as you did not wait that task.

Comment: @weichch good point, fixed. The issue remains though.

Comment: This does not seem to happen in a console app either. Something interesting going on there.